# Ansible: how to make an if inside if?

Tags: ansible

I would like to check if the variable in previous task is defined and if it was, what is its value. 
In order to do that I have to first check if the variable exists and then later check its value or the task crashes.
This is what I have so far (but not as if inside if and obviously not working):

```
 - name: "Checking other server availbility"
    uri:
      url: http://www.google.pl
      timeout: 5
    register: command_result_2
    when: command_result.status != 200

  - name: "Setting default server"
    command: echo http://www.google.pl
    register: SERVER_PATH
    when: 
      - command_result_2 is defined
      - command_result_2.status == 200
```

In my code the first task may or may not register a `command_result_2` variable.

Comment: could you show us what you need the server_path for - maybe there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: There are two servers and I need to check if the first one is active and set server_path to its address, if not check the second one, if neither is active i need to stop the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>I'm afraid you are trying to solve a problem with your solution, not your real problem, but here is an answer to the question.</sup>

You can use the [`default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) to return a value when the variable is not defined (in the example below 0 will never equal 200, so the task will run only when `command_result_2` is defined and equal to 200):

```
- name: "Setting default server"
  command: echo http://www.google.pl
  register: SERVER_PATH
  when: command_result_2|default(0) == 200
```

<sub>Please mind that the above task (`command: echo` + `register`) makes little sense in Ansible. And even if you used more appropriate `set_fact`, I have no clue why you'd want to run such a task in the first place.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I haven't noticed that I'm making a workaround earlier. Still the knowledge of how to deal with this is useful for my further development. Thanks